# which sharepoint project should be created in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I want to get some useful data from *.csv file through the retrieve query, then put these data in the reference column of the sharepoint list using the admin account.

Which sharepoint project in VS2010 should I choose? And what should I do in next?

## Thanks

如果我是要从 *.csv 文件中取一些数据 ，然后放到sharepoint上， 应该选择哪种工程呢？然后接下来应该怎么做呢？

谢谢

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what it is you are wanting to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to run this job once you could create a console application and let it run on the server. Include a reference to the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll to be able to use the Object Model of SharePoint. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633.aspx for an overview of the different objects you can use. (SharePoint 2010)

If you have no access to the server you could try the same using the webservices that sharepoint exposes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx for a list of the webservices in WSS3.0

But if you need it be done regularly your better of creating a webpart or a custom service to include into SharePoint. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/ee513148.aspx for an intro on building a WebPart for SP2010.

Google around, there is a lot to find about interaction with sharepoint through its object model.